# Fill a dropdown menu from 1 to 100 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I've tried to write a javascript code which fills the select tags with option tags from 1 to 100.

But instead of giving me 99 options, it gives me only one option with the 100 value on it.

I would be happy to understand and to know how to solve this problem.

```js
var selectAge = document.getElementById("selectAge");
document.onload = (function(){
  for(let i = 1; i<=100 ; i++)
    selectAge.innerHTML ="<option>" + i + "</option>";
})();
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    Your age:
    <select name="age" id="selectAge"></select>
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are overwriting the `innerHTML` upon each iteration of the loop.
One solution is to concatenate with the [addition assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment): `+=`.

```js
var selectAge = document.getElementById("selectAge");
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
  selectAge.innerHTML += "<option>" + i + "</option>";
```

```html
<select name="age" id="selectAge"></select>
```

---

As mentioned by Ivan, to avoid rewriting the `innerHTML` 100 times, I suggest building a string first:

```js
var selectAge = document.getElementById("selectAge");
var contents;

for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  contents += "<option>" + i + "</option>";
}

selectAge.innerHTML = contents;
```

```html
<select name="age" id="selectAge"></select>
```

Answer (score 5):

Beside (as already noted by others) you're using `=` instead of `+=` to concatenate, it's a bad idea to manipulate 100 times the DOM,
**instead, use `innerHTML` only once:**

```js
let ageOptions = "";
for(let i=1; i<=100 ; i++) ageOptions += `<option>${i}</option>`;

document.querySelector("[name=age]").innerHTML = ageOptions;
```

```html
Your age: <select name="age"></select>
```

Also, to make sure DOM is parsed ready to be manipulated, (instead of `window.onload` and similar) simply place your `<script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

Try just adding a  `+=`.

This will add the every single option from 0 to 100, because `+=` means that the value will be added to the value that previously existed.

```
selectAge.innerHTML +="<option>" + i + "</option>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Every loop you will assign new value to  `selectAge.innerHTML` but you actually want for every loop to add new value to the existing one. You can do it with `+=` witch is the same as `selectAge.innerHTML = selectAge.innerHTML + ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you must contact the changes to `innerHTML` in every epoch of your loop, see below codes:

```
const selectAge = document.getElementById("selectAge");
document.onload = ( () => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    selectAge.innerHTML += `<option>${i}</option>`;
})();
```

I write above code in `ES6` style, it is common for trend browsers now.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the innerHTML.

```js
var selectAge = document.getElementById("selectAge");
// use addEventlistener or you will overwrite other 'onload' events
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  for(let i = 1; i<=100 ; i++){
    let option = document.createElement('option');
        option.innerText = i;
    selectAge.appendChild( option );
  }
}); // end onload
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    Your age:
    <select name="age" id="selectAge"></select>
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: uhh why the hate?

Comment: I don't know why you got 3 negative vote!! your answer is true, you just didn't write code, just it!! they could didn't vote you

Comment: Thank you for the additional method: creating elements and appending them to the DOM.